# Safari & IE9 fires Page twice

Tags: asp.net, events, safari

I have an asp.net page which is working fine in chrome & mozilla but when i load it in safari or IE9, the page fires twice. and when it fire page second time the session become null. I am not getting why safari & IE9 fires page twice.

My code as follows :-

```
public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FBInstance fb;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Drivertab(Convert.ToInt32(GlobalVars.DriverType.PAVEMENT));
            Drivertab(Convert.ToInt32(GlobalVars.DriverType.OFFROAD));
            if (Request.Form["signed_request"] != null)
            {

                string payload = Request.Params["signed_request"].Split('.')[1];
                var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                var decodedJson = payload.Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
                var base64JsonArray = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedJson.PadRight(decodedJson.Length + (4 - decodedJson.Length % 4) % 4, '='));
                var json = encoding.GetString(base64JsonArray);
                //Response.Write(json.ToString());
                var o = JObject.Parse(json);
                var lPid = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("page.id")).Replace("\"", "");
                var isLiked = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("page.liked")).Replace("\"", "");
                var lUserId = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("user_id")).Replace("\"", "");

                {
                    string message = string.Empty;
                    DataTable FBUserData = StoredProcedures.ReadFacebookUserID(lUserId, out message);
                    hfIsUserAuthenticated.Value = "false";

                    if (FBUserData != null)
                    {
                        if (FBUserData.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            hfIsUserAuthenticated.Value = "true";
                            fb = new FBInstance();

                            fb.BUserID = Convert.ToInt32(FBUserData.Rows[0]["UserID"]);
                            fb.FBUserID = FBUserData.Rows[0]["FacebookUserID"].ToString();
                            fb.AuthToken = FBUserData.Rows[0]["AuthToken"].ToString();
                            fb.IsAuthenticated = Convert.ToBoolean(FBUserData.Rows[0]["IsActive"]);
                            fb.NoOfVote = 0;
                            Session[GlobalVars.FBSession] = fb;
                            hfFBUserID.Value = fb.FBUserID;
                            RecentVoteDriver(Convert.ToInt32(GlobalVars.DriverType.PAVEMENT), fb);
                            RecentVoteDriver(Convert.ToInt32(GlobalVars.DriverType.OFFROAD), fb);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }

protected void Drivertab(int driverTypeID)
    {

        DataTable dt = StoredProcedures.ReadDriverCard(driverTypeID);
        if (driverTypeID == 1)
        {
            dtDriverCard.DataSource = dt;
            dtDriverCard.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            dtDriverCard2.DataSource = dt;
            dtDriverCard2.DataBind();
        }
    }

public void RecentVoteDriver(int DriverTypeID, FBInstance fb)
    {
        DataTable dt = StoredProcedures.ReadRecentVote(fb.BUserID, DriverTypeID);

        if (DriverTypeID == 2)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DateTime VoteDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["VoteDateTime"]);
                if (VoteDate.Date != DateTime.Now.Date)
                {
                    Image1.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/DefaultDriver.jpg";
                }
                else
                {
                    DataTable Rdt = StoredProcedures.ReadRecentDriverCard(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["DriverCardID"]));
                    if (Rdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Image1.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/drivers/" + Rdt.Rows[0]["ImageURL"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Image1.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/DefaultDriver.jpg";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Image1.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/DefaultDriver.jpg";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DateTime VoteDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["VoteDateTime"]);
                if (VoteDate.Date != DateTime.Now.Date)
                {
                    Image2.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/DefaultDriver1.jpg";
                }
                else
                {
                    DataTable Rdt = StoredProcedures.ReadRecentDriverCard(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["DriverCardID"]));
                    if (Rdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Image2.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/drivers/" + Rdt.Rows[0]["ImageURL"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Image2.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/DefaultDriver1.jpg";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Image2.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/DefaultDriver1.jpg";
            }
        }
    }
```

Does any one have any solution.

thanks for your help

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post your problem code.

Comment: i am creating session on page load which becomes null when page load second time. the page fires second time automatically. i am not getting why safari fires page twice

Comment: How are you "creating session"? What do you mean by that? Please edit your post with more details. A Session is created automatically, but you can add values to it.

Comment: i m adding values in session..please check in my answer i have added code in it...!

Comment: do u have any solution.. because there is no error in my code... as i change in preferences setting ->block cookies= never. so i need help how to save cookies in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FBInstance fb;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Drivertab(Convert.ToInt32(GlobalVars.DriverType.PAVEMENT));
            Drivertab(Convert.ToInt32(GlobalVars.DriverType.OFFROAD));
            if (Request.Form["signed_request"] != null)
            {

                string payload = Request.Params["signed_request"].Split('.')[1];
                var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                var decodedJson = payload.Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
                var base64JsonArray = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedJson.PadRight(decodedJson.Length + (4 - decodedJson.Length % 4) % 4, '='));
                var json = encoding.GetString(base64JsonArray);
                //Response.Write(json.ToString());
                var o = JObject.Parse(json);
                var lPid = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("page.id")).Replace("\"", "");
                var isLiked = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("page.liked")).Replace("\"", "");
                var lUserId = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("user_id")).Replace("\"", "");

                {
                    string message = string.Empty;
                    DataTable FBUserData = StoredProcedures.ReadFacebookUserID(lUserId, out message);
                    hfIsUserAuthenticated.Value = "false";

                    if (FBUserData != null)
                    {
                        if (FBUserData.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            hfIsUserAuthenticated.Value = "true";
                            fb = new FBInstance();

                            fb.BUserID = Convert.ToInt32(FBUserData.Rows[0]["UserID"]);
                            fb.FBUserID = FBUserData.Rows[0]["FacebookUserID"].ToString();
                            fb.AuthToken = FBUserData.Rows[0]["AuthToken"].ToString();
                            fb.IsAuthenticated = Convert.ToBoolean(FBUserData.Rows[0]["IsActive"]);
                            fb.NoOfVote = 0;
                            Session[GlobalVars.FBSession] = fb;
                            hfFBUserID.Value = fb.FBUserID;
                            RecentVoteDriver(Convert.ToInt32(GlobalVars.DriverType.PAVEMENT), fb);
                            RecentVoteDriver(Convert.ToInt32(GlobalVars.DriverType.OFFROAD), fb);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }

protected void Drivertab(int driverTypeID)
    {

        DataTable dt = StoredProcedures.ReadDriverCard(driverTypeID);
        if (driverTypeID == 1)
        {
            dtDriverCard.DataSource = dt;
            dtDriverCard.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            dtDriverCard2.DataSource = dt;
            dtDriverCard2.DataBind();
        }
    }

public void RecentVoteDriver(int DriverTypeID, FBInstance fb)
    {
        DataTable dt = StoredProcedures.ReadRecentVote(fb.BUserID, DriverTypeID);

        if (DriverTypeID == 2)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DateTime VoteDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["VoteDateTime"]);
                if (VoteDate.Date != DateTime.Now.Date)
                {
                    Image1.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/DefaultDriver.jpg";
                }
                else
                {
                    DataTable Rdt = StoredProcedures.ReadRecentDriverCard(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["DriverCardID"]));
                    if (Rdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Image1.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/drivers/" + Rdt.Rows[0]["ImageURL"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Image1.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/DefaultDriver.jpg";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Image1.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/DefaultDriver.jpg";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DateTime VoteDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["VoteDateTime"]);
                if (VoteDate.Date != DateTime.Now.Date)
                {
                    Image2.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/DefaultDriver1.jpg";
                }
                else
                {
                    DataTable Rdt = StoredProcedures.ReadRecentDriverCard(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["DriverCardID"]));
                    if (Rdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Image2.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/drivers/" + Rdt.Rows[0]["ImageURL"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Image2.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/DefaultDriver1.jpg";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Image2.ImageUrl = GlobalVars.ImageURL + "/DefaultDriver1.jpg";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: dont add your code here im editing your question just accept it ok

Answer (score 0):

Try editing `RecentVoteDriver` setting this default value for  `Image1.ImageUrl` (could it happen that in some case none of that images in if-else clause are set?).

### Reason

Please look at the html as it is rendered on the page:

Every time it's present

```
<img src=""/>
```

double postback can happen, for some browser...

If this is the trouble, you can resolve it setting a default, blank, image for every button

```
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/blank.gif"...
```

Comment: i have given default values to Image1 and Image2 in aspx page and i have also checked there is no <img> tag with src="". i have given src to every asp.Image or <img> in aspx